# Entity Framework: Automatically Compute Members

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

We are utilizing Entity Framework Core. Currently there is table called `Sales`.
Anytime `Amount` is Inserted/Updated, the `AmountDividedbyTwo` column is also updated.

Typically team could use Persistent Computed Columns, but heard those can be slow sometimes. It can be easier to calculate in application side, especially we will have more complicated logic later. (only provided simple example below)

Here is scaffolded entity, we are not allowed to touch these (they are auto generated). 
Is there a method in Net Core to add another partial class, which will compute AmountDividedBy2.

How can this be done ?

**Scaffolded Entity**

```
public partial class Sales
{
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public float AmountDividedByTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it a must to save `AmountDividedByTwo` in db?

Comment: Of course you can always add a partial class containing getter-only computed properties.

Comment: hi @GertArnold please write in answer, and I can send points, thanks, original scaffold entity should remain intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ViewModels or DTOs i would suggest to just do it on a Mapper level when mapping from ViewModel/DTO to your Domain Object (Sales).

Here is how I would map it with Automapper:

```
CreateMap<SalesViewModel, Sales>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AmountDividedByTwo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount/2.0))
            ;
```

As noted in comments the first mapping is redundant, I wrote it for clarity sake.

Comment: The first `MapFrom` is redundant.

Comment: I agree, I wrote it for clarity only.